# node.js modules: Async vs Fibers.promise vs Q_oper8

Tags: multithreading, node.js, asynchronous, node-modules

Just wondering if anyone could give me a comparison of trade-offs between these modules for handling async events. Specifically, I'm interested in knowing about reasons to use Async instead of Fibers.promise, which I am using quite extensively at least in my test code right now. In particular, one of the major pluses I see in Fibers.promise is that I can keep the stack chain front bifurcating, making it possible to use `try { } catch { } finally`, and also allowing me to ensure that after a request has been handled that the response is ended.

Is anyone using Q_oper8? I found this on another page and was just wondering if that's already dead or if its something I should check out.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

I've never heard of Q_oper8, so I can't comment on it, but I'll come at this from the other direction. I heard about async first and Fiber (and its helper libraries) second, and I don't like the latter, actually.

### The Downsides of Fiber

#### Unfamiliarity for other Javascript developers

Fiber introduces the concept of co-routines to Javascript via a compiled `Fiber` native method that takes over the interpretation of the Javascript code passed to it, intercepting calls to `yield` to jump back to the waiting co-routine.

This may not matter to you, but if you need to work on a team, you'll have to teach the concept to your members (or hope they have experience with the concept from other languages, like Go).

#### No Windows Support

So, in order to use Fiber or any of the libraries written on top of it, you'll have to natively compile it for your platform first. I don't use Windows, but note that Fiber is not supported on Windows, so that restricts the utility of your own library off-the-bat. Which means you won't be finding general-purpose Node.js libraries written in Fiber *at all* (and you probably wouldn't have, anyways, since it adds a costly compilation step that you'd otherwise avoid with async).

#### Browser Incompatible

This means any code you write using Fiber *will not* be able to run in the browser, because you can't mix native code with the browser (nor would I as a browser user want you to), even if everything you write is "Javascript" (it's syntatically Javascript, but semantically not).

#### More Difficult Debugging

While the "callback hell" may be less visually pleasing, Continuation-Passing Style does have one very good thing going for it over Co-Routines -- you know exactly where a problem has occurred from the call stack and can trace backwards. Co-Routines enter the function at more than one point in the program, and can exit from *three kinds of calls*: `return`, `throw` and `yield()`, where the latter is also a return point.

With co-routines, you have cross-execution between two or more functions running "simultaneously", and you may have more than one set of co-routines running at the same time on the event loop. With traditional callbacks, you're guaranteed that the outer scope of the function is static during the execution of said function, so you only need to check those outer variables once if they're needed. Co-routines need these checks to be run after every `yield()` (since it's usage with the originating co-routine would be translated into a callback chain in real Javascript).

Basically, I think the co-routine *concept* is made more difficult to work with because it has to exist *inside* of the Javascript event loop, rather than being a method to implement one.

### What makes Async "better"?

#### Worse is Better

It's sort of the "worse-is-better" idea, actually. Rather than extend the Javascript language to try and get rid of its warts (and create new ones, in my opinion), Async is a pure-Javascript solution to cover them up, like makeup.

#### Control flow explicit

The Async functions describe different types of logic flow that needs to cross the event loop barrier, and the library covers up the implementation details of the callback code needed to implement that logic, and you just provide it functions it should run in roughly the linear order they will execute across the event loop.

If you're willing to drop the first indentation level around the async methods' arguments, you have no extra indentation versus Co-Routines and only a minor number of extra lines of `function(callback) {` declarations, like this:

```
var async = require('async');
var someArray = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];
async.forEach(someArray,
function(number, callback) {
    //Do something with the number
    callback();
}, function(err) {
    //Done doing stuff, or one of the calls to the previous function returned an error I need to deal with
});
```

In this case, you know that all of the variables your code is using could only have been changed before your code is run if they weren't changed by your code, so you can debug easier, and there is only one "return" mechanism: `callback()`. You either callback with nothing on success or pass the callback an error when something's gone wrong.

#### Code reuse not difficult

The above example makes code reuse difficult but it doesn't have to be. You can always pass in named functions as the parameters:

```
var async = require('async');

// Javascript doesn't care about declaration order within a scope,
// so order the declarations in a way that's most readable to you

async.forEach(someArray, frazzleNumber, doneFrazzling);

var someArray = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];

function frazzleNumber(number, callback) {
    // Do something to number
    callback();
}

function doneFrazzling(err) {
    // Do something or handle error
}
```

#### Functional, not imperative

The async module discourages the use of imperative-style flow control and encourages (requires, for the parts that cross the event loop) the use of functions for flow control.

The advantage of the functional style is that you can easily re-use the body of your loop or your conditional, and that you can create new control flow "verbs" that better match the flow of your code (demonstrated by the very existence of the async library), like the `async.auto` control flow method that implements dependency graph resolution for function call order. (You specify a series of named functions and list the other functions, if any, that it depends on to execute, and `auto` runs first the "independent" functions then the next function that can run based on when its dependent functions have finished running.)

Rather than writing your code to fit the imperative style dictated by your language, you write your code as the logic of the problem dictates, and implement the "glue" control flow to get it to happen.

#### In Summary

Fiber, by its very nature of extending the Javascript language, cannot develop a large ecosystem within Node.js, especially when Async gets 80% of the way on the looks department, and has none of the other downsides of co-routines in Javascript.

Comment: Wow thank you! This has certainly given me a lot to think about. It's closing time where I am but I'll think about it tonight and come back tomorrow if I have any questions.

Comment: I think I'm really understanding this now. Your argument comes down to simply what you say in your summary: That the functionality I'm looking for is provided in async, and therefore there's no reason to bastardize the language with co-routines. That if I embrace the functional paradigm life for me in javascript land will be prosperous :-)     Thank you thank you!

Comment: You're welcome. I'm not saying that Co-routines are *bad*. Just that they're bad in Javascript, because you have both co-routines and events happening at the same time, and any complex co-routine using Fiber *will* have to mix them (any I/O operation) and then you can get a weird situation with two co-routines running simultaneously and affecting each other's scope in unexpected ways. Co-routines in Go, outside of an event loop, are easier to understand and will have fewer subtle bugs because of it.

Comment: Maybe this wasn't the case, but Fibers are supported on windows these days.

Comment: Programmer unfamiliarity is not a good argument. Everything was unfamiliar to everyone at some point, and they only became popular by being useful.

Comment: @DavidEllis "two co-routines running simultaneously" - that is 100% false. Co-routines by definition cannot run simultaneously. They run one at a time. The same is true for Fibers.

Comment: That was an explanatory simplification. If you have two co-routines that are being accessed multiple times (to perform lazy list evaluation or what have you) they would be *interleaved* and one could affect global state used by the other in unexpected ways.

Comment: That's true, but its also true for any other method of synchronization. If you also introduce futures, you can control what continuations can interleave and which won't. Interleaving behavior isn't special to fibers.

Comment: So... why exactly do you keep nitpicking this response about once a year? Also "Fibers.promise" *is* a futures implementation, so I fail to see the point you're trying to make.

Comment: Unfamiliar: wrong. No windows support: wrong. Browser incompatible: true. Difficult debugging: wrong. For details and a bit of info on performance tradeoffs, see  https://github.com/yortus/asyncawait/issues/51#issuecomment-256698358

Comment: Unfamiliar: True, it's not part of the Javascript spec. You can't debate that. No windows support: True when I wrote this FOUR YEARS AGO. Difficult debugging: still true. Tell me succinctly how you debug it that doesn't require JS devs to use strace.

Comment: Unfamiliar: there is nothing about threading model in the JS Specs. Some JS engines (Rhino for ex) are even multi-threaded. Fibers code is structured like sync code => familiar. Windows: 4yrs ago => please update your answer. Debugging: every coroutine has a stack so you get perfect stack traces without any hacks + stepping through the code is just like stepping through sync code. See this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=duC1Sqy66IE

Comment: I presume you actually haven't read the ECMAScript specification. There is no way to interpret it as anything other than a single-threaded execution environment. Multithreading in some JS engines is accomplished outside of the language specification usually via message-passing of serialized data then copied into a parallel execution context and deserialized on the other side. This is how WebWorker Threads work in browsers that support it. How to deal with multithreading is a case-by-case basis and therefore is not familiar to devs and therefore neither would how to debug it.

Comment: Fibers is single-threaded. Can you point me to a section of the spec which would make JavaScript + fibers non compliant? JS itself does not provide the primitives to implement fibers (which may be your point - outside the language specification), but a host may enable it through additional APIs. This is what happens when you run node.js with the fibers add-on. OTOH, rhino can execute multiple threads on a shared JS scope (see xhttps://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Projects/Rhino/Scopes_and_Contexts#Scopes).

Answer (score 12):

The short answer:

- [Async](https://github.com/caolan/async) is a pure/classic javascript solution to managing single-thread asynchronousity
- [Fibers](https://github.com/laverdet/node-fibers) is a node.js extension for creating coroutines. It includes a futures library for managing single-thread asynchronousity.
- There are many other futures libraries (listed below) that don't require an extension of javascript.
- [Q_oper8](https://github.com/robtweed/Q-Oper8) is a node.js module for managing multi-process concurrency

Note that none of these offer "threads" and so none can be said to do multithreading (though there is a node.js extension for that too: [threads_a_gogo](https://github.com/xk/node-threads-a-gogo)).

## Async vs Fiber/futures

### Async

Async and Fibers/futures are different ways to solve the same problem: managing asynchronously resolving dependencies. Async seems to have many more "bells and whistles" than many other libraries that try to solve this problem, which in my opinion makes it worse (much more cognitive overhead - ie more crap to learn).

In javascript basic asynchronisity looks like this:

```
asyncCall(someParam, function(result) {
   useThe(result);
});
```

If you have a situation that requires more than just basic asynchronisity, like where you need the results of two asyncronous calls, you might do something like this:

```
asyncCall1(someParam, function(result0) {
  asyncCall2(someParam, function(result1) {
   use(result0, result1);
  }
});
```

Already starts to look like callback hell. Also its inefficient because the second call is waiting for the first call to complete even though it isn't dependent on it, not to mention the code doesn't even do any sort of reasonable error handling. Async provides one solution to writing it a little more efficiently:

```
async.parallel([
  function(callback) {
    asyncCall1(someParam, function(result0) {
      callback(null,result0);
    },
  function(callback) {
    asyncCall1(someParam, function(result1) {
      callback(null,result1);
    },
  }
],
function(err, results) {
  use(results[0], results[1]);
});
```

So to me, thats rather worse than callback hell, but to each his own I suppose. Despite it being ugly, it allows both calls to happen simultaneously (as long as they make non-blocking IO calls or something like that). Async has many more options for managing asynchronous code, so if you're interested take a look at [the documentation](https://github.com/caolan/async).

### Enter fiber/futures

The coroutines the Fibers module includes a futures library that uses coroutines to re-inject asynchronous events back into the current continuation (future.wait()).

Fibers is different from most other futures libraries because it allows the current continuation to wait on an asynchronous event - meaning it doesn't require the use of callbacks in order for you to get a value back from an async request - allowing asynchronous code to become synchronous-like. Read about coroutines for more about that.

Node.js has io functions like readFileSync, which lets you wait on the function in-line while it gets the file for you. This is not something that is normally done in javascript, and isn't something that can be written in pure javascript - it requires an extension like Fibers.

Going back to the same asynchronous example above, this is what it would look like with fibers/futures:

```
var future0 = asyncCall1(someParam);
var future1 = asyncCall2(someParam);
use(future0.wait(), future1.wait());
```

This is drastically simpler and just as efficient as the Async mess up there. It avoids callback-hell in an elegant efficient way. There are (minor) downsides though. David Ellis overstated many of the downsides, so I'll repeat the only valid one here:

#### Browser Incompatibility

By virtue of Fibers being a node.js extension, it will not be compatible with browsers. This will make sharing code that uses fibers impossible with both a node.js server and the browser. However, there is a strong argument that most asynchronous code you want on the server (filesystem, database, network calls) is *not* the same code you want on a browser (ajax calls). Maybe timeouts collide, but that seems like it.

Beyond that, the [streamline.js](https://github.com/Sage/streamlinejs) project has the ability to bridge this gap. Seems like it has a compilation process that can transform streamline.js code using synchronization and futures into pure javascript using the callback style, similar to the now unsupported [Narrative Javascript](http://www.neilmix.com/narrativejs/doc/). Streamline.js can use a couple different mechanisms behind the scenes, one being node.js Fibers, another being ECMAScript 6 generators, and the last being translation into callback-style javascript which I already mentioned.

#### More difficult debugging

This one seems like a valid, if minor, gripe. Even if you're just planning on using fibers/futures, and not using coroutines for anything else, there might still be confusing context switches because of unexpected function exit (and entrance) points.

#### Introduces pre-emptiveness into javascript

This is probably the most major problem with fibers, since it has the possibility (however unlikely) of introducing hard-to-understand bugs. Basically, because a Fiber `yield` can cause a temporary exit of a set of code to another undetermined function, its possible that some invalid state can be read or introduced. See [this article](http://calculist.org/blog/2011/12/14/why-coroutines-wont-work-on-the-web/) for more info. Personally, I think the incredible cleanness of fibers/futures and similar structures is well worth the rare insidious bugs. Many more bugs are caused by awful concurrency code.

#### Invalid gripes

- Not on windows: this just isn't true anymore
- Unfamiliarity with coroutines: A. Unfamiliarity is never a reason to shun something. If its good its good, regardless of how familiar you are with it. B. While coroutines and yields may be unfamiliar, futures are an easy concept to understand.

### Other futures libraries

There are many libraries that implement futures, where the concept may be called "futures", "deferred objects", or "promises". This includes libraries like [async-future](https://github.com/fresheneesz/asyncFuture), [streamline.js](https://github.com/Sage/streamlinejs), [Q](https://github.com/kriskowal/q), [when.js](https://github.com/cujojs/when), [promiscuous](https://github.com/RubenVerborgh/promiscuous/), [jQuery's deferred](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/), [coolaj86's futures](https://github.com/coolaj86/futures), [kriszyp's promises](https://github.com/kriszyp/node-promise), and [Narrative Javascript](http://www.neilmix.com/narrativejs/doc/).

Most of these use callbacks to resolve the futures, which get around many of the problems Fibers introduces. However, they aren't quite as clean as fibers/futures, tho they are far cleaner than Async. Here's the same example again using my own [async-future](https://github.com/fresheneesz/asyncFuture):

```
var future0 = asyncCall1(someParam);
var future1 = asyncCall2(someParam);
Future.all([future0, future1]).then(function(results) {
  use(results[0], results[1])
}).done()
```

## Q_oper8

Q_oper8 is really a different beast. It runs jobs in a queue using a pool of processes. Since [javascript is single-threaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2734025/is-javascript-guaranteed-to-be-single-threaded)*, and javascript doesn't have native threading available, processes are the usual way to take advantage of more than one processor in node.js. Q_oper8 is intended as an alternative to managing processes using node.js's child_process module.

Answer (score 2):

You should also check out [Step](https://github.com/creationix/step).

It handles only a small subset of what async can do, but I think the code is much easier to read. It's great for just handling the normal case of doing a sequence of things, with some of those things happening in parallel.

I tend to use Step for the bulk of my logic, and then use async occasionally when I need to apply methods repeatedly in serial or parallel execution (ie - call this function until, or call this function on each element of this array).

Answer (score 1):

I'm using jQuery's Deferred functionality on the client and jQuery Deferred for nodejs on the server in place of nested callbacks.  It has greatly reduced the code and made things so readable.

http://techishard.wordpress.com/2012/05/23/promises-promises-a-concise-pattern-for-getting-and-showing-my-json-array-with-jquery-and-underscore/

http://techishard.wordpress.com/2012/05/29/making-mongoose-keep-its-promises-on-the-server/

Comment: It doesn't answer the question at all. You're just saying what you use, you're not giving a comparison of the things he asked for.